# What ASP.NET MVC data annotation is used for the Range summary error message?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model property defined like:

```
    [Display(Name = "Monthly Setting")]
    [Required]
    [Range(1,12, ErrorMessage="Month Setting must be between 1 and 12")]
    public int KPIMonthSetting { get; set; }
```

I find that when the range is exceeded that the ValidationMessageFor, like:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KPIMonthSetting, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

shows the message I'm expecting, but the ValidationSummary:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Shows:

"The value entered, "16", is invalid for the field: K PI Month Setting."

How can I control this message? I at least want to remove the space between K and PI.

Comment: what two messages are you getting and btw its working fine with me

Answer (score 0):

By setting 'true' as a first argument to the helper you are excluding property errors. Pass 'false' and you should see the same message as in `ValidationMessageFor`:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Definitely a step in the right direction, but now I see both messages: